# unknown column error when trying to open table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so after running the query below, whenever i try to open the affected table, it says "unknown column doc.section in order clause". i can still run queries on the said table but i can no longer access the table by using the left panel on phpmyadmin.

query:

```
select pending.*
from (
    select distinct doc.*, users.dept_id
    from list_users users, exit_doc doc
    inner join ( 
        select q.section, 
        max(q.subsection) subsection
        from exit_doc q 
        group by q.section ) latest
    on doc.section = latest.section
    and doc.subsection = latest.subsection
    where doc.user_id = users.user_id) pending
inner join (
    select approvers.dept_id, approvers.role_code 
    from approvers 
    where user_id = 10004 
    and delete_flag = 0) user
on pending.next_user = user.role_code 
and pending.dept_id = user.dept_id
```

did my query somehow affect the structure of the table? the error said unknown column on order clause but i didnt use any order in my query?

Comment: Don't mix explicit JOIN and implicit, comma separated joins.

Comment: i dont quite understand, can you please elaborate?

Comment: from list_users users, exit_doc doc - bad, from list_users users join exit_doc doc on doc.user_id = users.user_id - better.

Comment: the users and docs are two different table and joined by a third 'table' named latest

Comment: Your query has no `order by`, so it is not generating the error you mention.

Comment: yes i noticed that too, which is why im confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried clearing your browser's cookies and cache?